# Custom design for Twitter button with events

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I've got a custom tweet button:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com;text=myText;size=l&amp;count=none" target="_blank">
    <div>
        <img src="/assets/twitter-logo.jpg">
        <span>Twitter</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Now I want to achieve some result after the tweet has been published. To do so, I've looked at the Twitter Events API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
        alert("Tweet Successful");
    });
</script>
```

However, this API only works on non-custom buttons (`twitter-share-button` class).

Anyone has managed to create a custom button which listens to events?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add the `twitter-share-button` class to your custom button element? Did you try that already? If it breaks styling or so, you can always overrule that Twitter specific styling with custom stylesheets.

Comment: The twitter-share-button class is used by the Twitter javascript library to delete its contents and insert an iframe.

Comment: Good call @Mateu. I didn't check the exact working of their library; was just thinking out loud what I would do. By the way I suppose the code example you provided is an *example* and not a carbon copy of your actual code? Since there is a typo in your code to small for me to edit: `wttr.events.bind` should be `twttr.events.bind`

Comment: Just an error when copying. Fixed

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can have a custom **link and still have the web intents**!

The **key** is, instead of your link pointing to "https://twitter.com/share" it should point to "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"

like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet</a>
```

This way you can use the web intents like you were trying:

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
  // Do something there
  alert('Tweeted');
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmoliveira/aXCNX/)

Comment: How can i include the link i want to twit with this? Please help me.

Comment: @GreenFox Like this? [Tweet with a link](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnunooliveira.me) Is this what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I got some one with a share action

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="pincheregio" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>

<script>
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

      twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
        alert("paso");
      });

    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aXCNX/139/

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT WASTE your time with "tweet" event. Unlike other social networks, twitter will fire this even regardless was the tweet successfully completed or user just closed the window. So instead use code bellow:

```
jQuery('#twitter').off('click').on('click', function() {
  var field_list = {
    url: 'https://example.com/',
    text: 'Some random text',
    hashtags: 'myhashtag,anothertag',
  }
  window.open('https://twitter.com/share?'+jQuery.param(field_list), '_blank', 'width=550,height=420').focus();
});
```