# Replace tweet button icon

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have a twitter share button that is created dynamically:

Html:

```
    <a id="twitter_publish" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="3imit" data-count="none"></a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Javascript:

```
function tweetSetup() {
    $("#twitter_publish").remove();
    $(".twitter-share-button").remove();
    var tweet = $('<a>')
        .attr('href', "https://twitter.com/share")
        .attr('id', "twitter_publish")
        .attr('class', "twitter-share-button")
        .attr('data-lang', "en")
        .attr('data-via', "3imit")
        .attr('data-count', "none")
        .attr('data-text', "Take a look at this:")
        .attr('data-url', $("#some_link").val())
        .text('Tweet');

    $("#facebook_publish").after(tweet);
    twttr.widgets.load();
    $("#twitter-share-button").show();
}
```

I would like to replace the default tweet icon with my own icon. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has an example on how to do that [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) (scroll to bottom, "Build Your Own Tweet Button"):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #custom-tweet-button a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 20px;
    background: url('https://twitter.com/favicons/favicon.ico') 1px center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

</style>

<div id="custom-tweet-button">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a problem with that: I need to change the share url dynamically so I create the button via javascript and than it turns to iframe and my css is not applicable to <a> inside the iframe.

Comment: I think the link is down - can't find the "Build Your Own Tweet Button" link.

Comment: I also cannot find the "Build Your Own Tweet Button" link anywhere on the page, however I still see other pages with customized buttons. Is Twitter phasing this functionality out?

Comment: I found https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent which includes instructions for using just a URL to share something.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer on this question:

[twitter button, with events and custom design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413159/twitter-button-with-events-and-custom-design)

You can have a custom link and still use javascript API. 
For your case, **your link should point to** https://twitter.com/intent/tweet
and **you should add the query parameters you need** to the url like this for example:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoururl.com&text=your%20text">Tweet</a>
```